# SVG path animation glich in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, safari, svg-animate

I'm trying to morph SVGs and it seems to be working fine for several browsers (Chrome, Edge, Mozilla) except for Safari. In Safari the animation is super glitchy.
My Safari version is: Version 13.1.1.

**The problem:** SVGs are displayed and animated correctly in Chrome, Edge, Mozilla but Safari fails to render the different SVGs correctly and adds weird transition effects to the animation (Glitch). I'm not sure if this comes from simply not rendering the SVG correctly, or if it's a bug in the animation. Either way, I can't find a good fix. I'd appreciate any kind of help and input as I've been stuck quite some time with this problem. Thank you!
It's hard to describe what is actually happening, therefore I enclosed my sandbox, so you can take a better look:

**My sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/safari-svg-animation-bug-9b2u0

**Quick Peak:**

```js
<section id="forms">
                <svg className="formItem"
                    id="ab9e6db3-c004-49c5-b031-1fda9a52585a"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1891.65 1049.79" preserveAspectRatio="none meet">
                    <path id="form">
                        <animate id="animationToCheck"
                            repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="d" dur="12s"
                            values="M 0 807.069 C 0 870.49 52.181 921.904 116.548 921.904 C 352.448 921.904 588.347 921.904 824.247 921.904 C 851.529 921.904 877.68 932.642 896.886 951.735 C 919.764 974.477 942.642 997.218 965.52 1019.96 C 984.725 1039.05 1010.88 1049.79 1038.16 1049.79 C 1280.793 1049.79 1523.427 1049.79 1766.06 1049.79 C 1835.7 1049.79 1892.05 993.957 1891.65 925.337 C 1891.65 744.426 1891.65 563.516 1891.65 382.605 C 1891.54 362.196 1882.99 342.715 1867.99 328.643 C 1806.16 271.549 1744.33 214.455 1682.5 157.361 C 1668.33 144.066 1649.51 136.65 1629.94 136.65 C 1541.943 136.65 1453.947 136.65 1365.95 136.65 C 1345.08 136.65 1325.07 128.482 1310.31 113.945 C 1279.443 83.532 1248.577 53.12 1217.71 22.707 C 1202.96 8.168 1182.94 0.001 1162.08 0.001 C 813.569 0.001 465.059 0.001 116.548 0.001 C 52.179 0.001 0 51.413 0 114.835 C 0 114.835 0 114.835 0 114.835 L 0 807.069;  
    
                            M 0 570.538 C 0 810.163 210.872 1004.15 471.363 1004.15 C 570.598 1004.15 657.428 969.914 694.64 969.914 C 756.662 969.914 789.223 989.883 821.009 1009.852 C 852.795 1029.821 883.807 1049.79 942.727 1049.79 C 1029.56 1049.79 1097.78 992.734 1128.79 924.271 C 1197.01 804.459 1327.26 724.582 1488.51 724.582 C 1562.94 724.582 1618.76 741.699 1662.17 741.699 C 1786.22 741.699 1891.65 650.412 1891.65 530.601 C 1891.65 483.056 1884.586 436.62 1871.349 392.245 C 1858.112 347.87 1838.702 305.555 1814.008 266.251 C 1789.314 226.947 1759.338 190.655 1724.967 158.324 C 1690.598 125.994 1651.834 97.625 1609.569 74.17 C 1567.303 50.714 1521.534 32.172 1473.152 19.493 C 1424.771 6.815 1373.777 0 1321.06 0 C 1041.96 0 942.727 193.982 769.065 193.982 C 676.033 193.982 614.012 131.223 471.363 131.223 C 341.118 131.223 223.277 181.145 137.997 261.02 C 52.718 340.896 0 450.724 0 570.538 L 0 570.538;
                          
                            M 1321.06 1.5 C 1041.96 1.5 942.727 195.482 769.065 195.482 C 676.033 195.482 614.012 132.723 471.363 132.723 C 210.872 132.723 0 332.411 0 572.038 C 0 572.038 0 572.038 0 572.038 C 0 811.663 210.872 1005.65 471.363 1005.65 C 570.598 1005.65 657.428 971.414 694.64 971.414 C 818.683 971.414 824.886 1051.29 942.727 1051.29 C 1029.56 1051.29 1097.78 994.234 1128.79 925.771 C 1197.01 805.959 1327.26 726.082 1488.51 726.082 C 1562.94 726.082 1618.76 743.199 1662.17 743.199 C 1786.22 743.199 1891.65 651.912 1891.65 532.101 C 1891.65 389.466 1828.078 256.816 1724.967 159.824 C 1621.858 62.833 1479.21 1.5 1321.06 1.5;
                          
                            M 1563.24 163.289 C 1412.17 163.289 1366.19 267.156 1169.15 267.156 C 847.304 267.156 834.166 0.997 499.186 0.997 C 361.253 0.997 236.457 56.176 146.144 144.626 C 55.83 233.076 0 354.796 0 487.876 C 0 617.71 43.058 723.74 118.472 807.41 C 193.885 891.081 301.652 952.391 431.071 992.783 C 560.49 1033.175 711.559 1052.65 873.576 1052.65 C 970.457 1052.65 1082.527 1040.072 1196.137 1015.526 C 1309.746 990.979 1424.896 954.464 1527.935 906.588 C 1630.974 858.712 1721.902 799.476 1787.072 729.487 C 1852.241 659.499 1891.65 578.759 1891.65 487.876 C 1891.65 312.599 1740.59 163.289 1563.24 163.289 C 1563.24 163.289 1563.24 163.289 1563.24 163.289;
                          
                            M 1563.24 163.289 C 1512.883 163.289 1474.203 174.83 1437.713 190.217 C 1401.223 205.605 1366.922 224.84 1325.324 240.228 C 1283.726 255.615 1234.83 267.156 1169.15 267.156 C 1061.868 267.156 988.887 237.583 926.853 198.152 C 864.819 158.721 813.732 109.432 750.239 70.001 C 686.746 30.57 610.846 0.997 499.186 0.997 C 223.321 0.997 0 221.715 0 487.876 C 0 877.377 387.526 1052.65 873.576 1052.65 C 1067.338 1052.65 1321.857 1002.34 1527.935 906.588 C 1734.013 810.836 1891.65 669.643 1891.65 487.876 C 1891.65 312.599 1740.59 163.289 1563.24 163.289 L 1563.24 163.289;
                          
                            M 1314.86 1.498 C 1253.75 1.498 1204.21 48.746 1204.21 107.029 C 1204.21 107.029 1204.21 107.029 1204.21 107.029 C 1204.21 145.074 1204.21 183.118 1204.21 221.163 C 1198.02 319.185 1112.74 396.862 1008.41 396.862 C 952.164 396.862 901.523 374.227 865.758 338.06 C 779.689 221.002 637.228 144.422 475.935 144.422 C 213.083 144.422 0 347.639 0 598.321 C 0 849.002 213.083 1052.22 475.935 1052.22 C 878.057 1052.22 1280.178 1052.22 1682.3 1052.22 C 1797.92 1052.22 1891.65 962.827 1891.65 852.557 C 1891.65 568.871 1891.65 285.184 1891.65 1.498 L 1314.86 1.498;
                          
                            M 1204.21 107.029 L 1204.21 221.163 C 1198.02 319.185 1112.74 396.862 1008.41 396.862 C 952.164 396.862 901.523 374.227 865.758 338.06 C 779.689 221.002 637.228 144.422 475.935 144.422 C 213.083 144.422 0 347.639 0 598.321 C 0 849.002 213.083 1052.22 475.935 1052.22 L 1079.118 1052.22 C 1280.178 1052.22 1481.239 1052.22 1682.3 1052.22 C 1797.92 1052.22 1891.65 962.827 1891.65 852.557 C 1891.65 568.871 1891.65 285.184 1891.65 1.498 L 1314.86 1.498 C 1253.75 1.498 1204.21 48.746 1204.21 107.029 Z;
                          
                            M 1463.01 6.176 L 1057.81 254.982 C 1052.84 258.036 1047.11 259.654 1041.26 259.654 C 704.681 259.654 368.101 259.654 31.522 259.654 C 14.113 259.654 0 273.705 0 291.038 C 0 534.045 0 777.053 0 1020.06 C 0 1037.39 14.113 1051.44 31.522 1051.44 L 1255.04 1051.44 C 1260.9 1051.44 1266.65 1049.82 1271.63 1046.75 C 1473.323 922.496 1675.017 798.243 1876.71 673.989 C 1891.5 664.879 1896.09 645.564 1886.96 630.825 L 1506.39 16.414 C 1497.25 1.661 1477.82 -2.923 1463.01 6.176 Z;
                          
                            M 1463.01 6.176 L 1057.81 254.982 C 1052.84 258.036 1047.11 259.654 1041.26 259.654 C 872.97 259.654 704.681 259.654 536.391 259.654 C 368.101 259.654 199.812 259.654 31.522 259.654 C 14.113 259.654 0 273.705 0 291.038 C 0 534.045 0 777.053 0 1020.06 C 0 1037.39 14.113 1051.44 31.522 1051.44 C 167.468 1051.44 303.415 1051.44 439.361 1051.44 C 575.308 1051.44 711.254 1051.44 847.201 1051.44 C 983.147 1051.44 1119.094 1051.44 1255.04 1051.44 C 1260.9 1051.44 1266.65 1049.82 1271.63 1046.75 L 1876.71 673.989 C 1891.5 664.879 1896.09 645.564 1886.96 630.825 L 1506.39 16.414 C 1497.25 1.661 1477.82 -2.923 1463.01 6.176 Z;
                          
                            M 1781.32 204.376 L 965.63 204.376 C 942.423 204.376 920.613 193.977 905.134 176.477 C 810.174 69.126 672.276 1.5 518.695 1.5 C 232.227 1.5 0 236.504 0 526.396 C 0 528.159 0.115 529.891 0.133 531.651 C -0.279 651.969 39.374 762.896 106.535 851.406 C 193.202 965.627 324.64 1034.58 465.214 1048.52 C 466.364 1048.64 467.529 1048.7 468.68 1048.81 C 476.107 1049.5 483.539 1050.15 491.01 1050.53 C 498.494 1050.93 506.04 1051.09 513.605 1051.16 C 515.166 1051.17 516.718 1051.29 518.282 1051.29 L 1803.72 1051.29 C 1852.28 1051.29 1891.65 1011.45 1891.65 962.305 L 1891.65 316.029 C 1891.65 254.365 1842.26 204.376 1781.32 204.376 Z;
                          
                            M 1781.32 204.376 C 1690.688 204.376 1600.056 204.376 1509.423 204.376 C 1418.791 204.376 1328.159 204.376 1237.527 204.376 C 1146.894 204.376 1056.262 204.376 965.63 204.376 C 942.423 204.376 920.613 193.977 905.134 176.477 C 810.174 69.126 672.276 1.5 518.695 1.5 C 375.461 1.5 245.787 60.251 151.922 155.238 C 58.057 250.226 0 381.45 0 526.396 C 0 528.159 0.115 529.891 0.133 531.651 C -0.279 651.969 39.374 762.896 106.535 851.406 C 193.202 965.627 324.64 1034.58 465.214 1048.52 C 466.364 1048.64 467.529 1048.7 468.68 1048.81 C 476.107 1049.5 483.539 1050.15 491.01 1050.53 C 498.494 1050.93 506.04 1051.09 513.605 1051.16 C 515.166 1051.17 516.718 1051.29 518.282 1051.29 C 946.761 1051.29 1375.241 1051.29 1803.72 1051.29 C 1852.28 1051.29 1891.65 1011.45 1891.65 962.305 C 1891.65 854.592 1891.65 746.88 1891.65 639.167 C 1891.65 531.454 1891.65 423.742 1891.65 316.029 C 1891.65 254.365 1842.26 204.376 1781.32 204.376 C 1781.32 204.376 1781.32 204.376 1781.32 204.376;
                          
                            M 1629.94 136.65 C 1541.943 136.65 1453.947 136.65 1365.95 136.65 C 1345.08 136.65 1325.07 128.482 1310.31 113.945 C 1279.443 83.532 1248.577 53.12 1217.71 22.707 C 1202.96 8.168 1182.94 0.001 1162.08 0.001 C 813.569 0.001 465.059 0.001 116.548 0.001 C 52.179 0.001 0 51.413 0 114.835 C 0 114.835 0 114.835 0 114.835 C 0 345.58 0 576.324 0 807.069 C 0 870.49 52.181 921.904 116.548 921.904 C 234.498 921.904 352.448 921.904 470.397 921.904 C 588.347 921.904 706.297 921.904 824.247 921.904 C 851.529 921.904 877.68 932.642 896.886 951.735 C 919.764 974.477 942.642 997.218 965.52 1019.96 C 984.725 1039.05 1010.88 1049.79 1038.16 1049.79 C 1280.793 1049.79 1523.427 1049.79 1766.06 1049.79 C 1835.7 1049.79 1892.05 993.957 1891.65 925.337 C 1891.65 744.426 1891.65 563.516 1891.65 382.605 C 1891.54 362.196 1882.99 342.715 1867.99 328.643 C 1806.16 271.549 1744.33 214.455 1682.5 157.361 C 1668.33 144.066 1649.51 136.65 1629.94 136.65;
                          
                            M 0 807.069 C 0 870.49 52.181 921.904 116.548 921.904 C 352.448 921.904 588.347 921.904 824.247 921.904 C 851.529 921.904 877.68 932.642 896.886 951.735 C 919.764 974.477 942.642 997.218 965.52 1019.96 C 984.725 1039.05 1010.88 1049.79 1038.16 1049.79 C 1280.793 1049.79 1523.427 1049.79 1766.06 1049.79 C 1835.7 1049.79 1892.05 993.957 1891.65 925.337 C 1891.65 744.426 1891.65 563.516 1891.65 382.605 C 1891.54 362.196 1882.99 342.715 1867.99 328.643 C 1806.16 271.549 1744.33 214.455 1682.5 157.361 C 1668.33 144.066 1649.51 136.65 1629.94 136.65 C 1541.943 136.65 1453.947 136.65 1365.95 136.65 C 1345.08 136.65 1325.07 128.482 1310.31 113.945 C 1279.443 83.532 1248.577 53.12 1217.71 22.707 C 1202.96 8.168 1182.94 0.001 1162.08 0.001 C 813.569 0.001 465.059 0.001 116.548 0.001 C 52.179 0.001 0 51.413 0 114.835 C 0 114.835 0 114.835 0 114.835 L 0 807.069" />
                    </path>
                </svg>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I've found out is that Safari has problems with SVG Masks and so I needed to work with Forms. I also had troubles with simple SVG Icons and I solved it the following way:

```
<svg width="21" height="20" viewBox="0 0 21 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g clip-path="url(#clip0)">
<path d="M15.8245 5.975C15.7859 5.93108 15.7385 5.89576 15.6854 5.87136C15.6323 5.84695 15.5746 5.83399 15.5162 5.83333H12.3745V4.65833C12.3745 4.425 12.4245 4.15833 12.7995 4.15833H15.2995C15.3544 4.16067 15.4091 4.15065 15.4596 4.12902C15.5101 4.10738 15.555 4.07468 15.5912 4.03333C15.6646 3.95714 15.7064 3.85583 15.7078 3.75V0.416667C15.7078 0.30616 15.6639 0.200179 15.5858 0.122039C15.5077 0.0438987 15.4017 0 15.2912 0L11.6828 0C7.68285 0 7.37451 3.41667 7.37451 4.45833V5.83333H5.29118C5.18067 5.83333 5.07469 5.87723 4.99655 5.95537C4.91841 6.03351 4.87451 6.13949 4.87451 6.25V9.58333C4.87451 9.69384 4.91841 9.79982 4.99655 9.87796C5.07469 9.9561 5.18067 10 5.29118 10H7.37451V19.5833C7.37451 19.6938 7.41841 19.7998 7.49655 19.878C7.57469 19.9561 7.68067 20 7.79118 20H11.9578C12.0684 20 12.1743 19.9561 12.2525 19.878C12.3306 19.7998 12.3745 19.6938 12.3745 19.5833V10H15.1662C15.2698 10.0005 15.37 9.96239 15.447 9.89304C15.524 9.8237 15.5725 9.72814 15.5828 9.625L15.9328 6.29167C15.9377 6.23426 15.9305 6.17648 15.9119 6.12198C15.8932 6.06747 15.8635 6.01743 15.8245 5.975Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
<defs>
<clipPath id="clip0">
<rect width="20" height="20" fill="white" transform="translate(0.707886)"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>
```

So to solve this problem I simply deleted the `g` and `clipPath` and `defs` tags and it worked just fine afterwards. So my SVG Code looked like this after I edited it:

```
<svg width="21" height="20" viewBox="0 0 21 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M15.8245 5.975C15.7859 5.93108 15.7385 5.89576 15.6854 5.87136C15.6323 5.84695 15.5746 5.83399 15.5162 5.83333H12.3745V4.65833C12.3745 4.425 12.4245 4.15833 12.7995 4.15833H15.2995C15.3544 4.16067 15.4091 4.15065 15.4596 4.12902C15.5101 4.10738 15.555 4.07468 15.5912 4.03333C15.6646 3.95714 15.7064 3.85583 15.7078 3.75V0.416667C15.7078 0.30616 15.6639 0.200179 15.5858 0.122039C15.5077 0.0438987 15.4017 0 15.2912 0L11.6828 0C7.68285 0 7.37451 3.41667 7.37451 4.45833V5.83333H5.29118C5.18067 5.83333 5.07469 5.87723 4.99655 5.95537C4.91841 6.03351 4.87451 6.13949 4.87451 6.25V9.58333C4.87451 9.69384 4.91841 9.79982 4.99655 9.87796C5.07469 9.9561 5.18067 10 5.29118 10H7.37451V19.5833C7.37451 19.6938 7.41841 19.7998 7.49655 19.878C7.57469 19.9561 7.68067 20 7.79118 20H11.9578C12.0684 20 12.1743 19.9561 12.2525 19.878C12.3306 19.7998 12.3745 19.6938 12.3745 19.5833V10H15.1662C15.2698 10.0005 15.37 9.96239 15.447 9.89304C15.524 9.8237 15.5725 9.72814 15.5828 9.625L15.9328 6.29167C15.9377 6.23426 15.9305 6.17648 15.9119 6.12198C15.8932 6.06747 15.8635 6.01743 15.8245 5.975Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```